# how to use this bottom tab bar with react native?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I am using the react navigation package. how can i make this bottom tab bar?

I couldn't find how to do it with this bottom tab bar react navigation. Anyone know how to do it in react native?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can try [@react-navigation/bottom-tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/) and `tabBar` props to custom BottomTab:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomMenu = (props) => {
  return (
    // render your design
  )
}

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <BottomMenu {...props} />}>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```